# How many permutations are possible of $n_1$ a's, $n_2$ b's, and $n_3$ c's, such that no two a's and no two b's are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given $n_1$ number of a's, $n_2$ number of b's, $n_3$ number of c's.

They form a sequence using all these characters such that no two a's and no two b's are adjacent.

(a and b can be adjacent, but two a's or b's cannot be adjacent. c has no restrictions.)

for example : acbccab is valid for $n_1=2$, $n_2=2$, $n_3=3$

but,

cbcbcaa is not valid as two a's are adjacent.

I have tries lot of things but nothing worked.

Can somebody tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based upon generating functions of **Smirnov words**. These are words with no equal consecutive characters. (See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.)

> We have $n_1$ $a$'s, $n_2$ $b$'s and $n_3$ $c$'s and are looking  for Smirnov words of length $n_1+n_2+n_3$.
>
> A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over the three letter alphabet $V=\{a,b,c\}$ is given by
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{a}{1+a}-\frac{b}{1+b}-\frac{c}{1+c}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In fact there is no restriction given for the character $c$. We respect this by substituting 
\begin{align*}
c\to c+c^2+c^3+\cdots=\frac{c}{1-c}
\end{align*}

> We so obtain from (1) the generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{a}{1+a}-\frac{b}{1+b}-\frac{\frac{c}{1-c}}{1+\frac{c}{1-c}}\right)^{-1}
> =\color{blue}{\frac{(1+a)(1+b)}{1-c-ab-ac-bc-abc}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We  use      the *coefficient of*  operator  $[z^n]$     to  denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series $A(z)$.

> The number of wanted words of length $n_1+n_2+n_3$ is therefore 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left[a^{n_1}b^{n_2}c^{n_3}\right]&\left(1-\frac{a}{1+a}-\frac{b}{1+b}-\frac{\frac{c}{1+c}}{1+\frac{c}{1+c}}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\left[a^{n_1}b^{n_2}c^{n_3}\right]\frac{(1+a)(1+b)}{1-c-ab-ac-bc-abc}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> *Example:*
>
> We consider the example of OP setting $(n_1,n_2,n_3)=(2,2,3)$ and we obtain from (3) with some help of Wolfram Alpha
>   \begin{align*}
> \left[a^2b^2c^3\right]\frac{(1+a)(1+b)}{1-c-ab-ac-bc-abc}\color{blue}{=110}
> \end{align*}

The $110$ valid words are listed below with OPs stated word marked in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$.

\begin{array}{cccccc}
\mathrm{ababccc}&\mathrm{acbacbc}&\mathrm{bacaccb}&\mathrm{bcbacca}&\mathrm{cacbcab}&\mathrm{ccabcab}\\
\mathrm{abacbcc}&\mathrm{acbaccb}&\mathrm{bacbacc}&\mathrm{bcbcaca}&\mathrm{cacbcba}&\mathrm{ccabcba}\\
\mathrm{abaccbc}&\mathrm{acbcabc}&\mathrm{bacbcac}&\mathrm{bccabac}&\mathrm{caccbab}&\mathrm{ccacbab}\\
\mathrm{abacccb}&\mathrm{acbcacb}&\mathrm{bacbcca}&\mathrm{bccabca}&\mathrm{cbabacc}&\mathrm{ccbabac}\\
\mathrm{abcabcc}&\mathrm{acbcbac}&\mathrm{baccabc}&\mathrm{bccacab}&\mathrm{cbabcac}&\mathrm{ccbabca}\\
\mathrm{abcacbc}&\mathrm{acbcbca}&\mathrm{baccacb}&\mathrm{bccacba}&\mathrm{cbabcca}&\mathrm{ccbacab}\\
\mathrm{abcaccb}&\color{blue}{\mathrm{acbccab}}&\mathrm{baccbac}&\mathrm{bccbaca}&\mathrm{cbacabc}&\mathrm{ccbacba}\\
\mathrm{abcbacc}&\mathrm{acbccba}&\mathrm{baccbca}&\mathrm{bcccaba}&\mathrm{cbacacb}&\mathrm{ccbcaba}\\
\mathrm{abcbcac}&\mathrm{accabcb}&\mathrm{bacccab}&\mathrm{cababcc}&\mathrm{cbacbac}&\mathrm{cccabab}\\
\mathrm{abcbcca}&\mathrm{accbabc}&\mathrm{bacccba}&\mathrm{cabacbc}&\mathrm{cbacbca}&\mathrm{cccbaba}\\
\mathrm{abccabc}&\mathrm{accbacb}&\mathrm{bcabacc}&\mathrm{cabaccb}&\mathrm{cbaccab}&\\
\mathrm{abccacb}&\mathrm{accbcab}&\mathrm{bcabcac}&\mathrm{cabcabc}&\mathrm{cbaccba}&\\
\mathrm{abccbac}&\mathrm{accbcba}&\mathrm{bcabcca}&\mathrm{cabcacb}&\mathrm{cbcabac}&\\
\mathrm{abccbca}&\mathrm{acccbab}&\mathrm{bcacabc}&\mathrm{cabcbac}&\mathrm{cbcabca}&\\
\mathrm{acbcabc}&\mathrm{babaccc}&\mathrm{bcacacb}&\mathrm{cabcbca}&\mathrm{cbcacab}&\\
\mathrm{acbcacb}&\mathrm{babcacc}&\mathrm{bcacbac}&\mathrm{cabccab}&\mathrm{cbcacba}&\\
\mathrm{acabcbc}&\mathrm{babccac}&\mathrm{bcacbca}&\mathrm{cabccba}&\mathrm{cbcbaca}&\\
\mathrm{acabccb}&\mathrm{babccca}&\mathrm{bcaccab}&\mathrm{cacabcb}&\mathrm{cbccaba}&\\
\mathrm{acacbcb}&\mathrm{bacabcc}&\mathrm{bcaccba}&\mathrm{cacbabc}&\mathrm{ccababc}&\\
\mathrm{acbabcc}&\mathrm{bacacbc}&\mathrm{bcbacac}&\mathrm{cacbacb}&\mathrm{ccabacb}&\\
\end{array}

Comment: how will i find the coefficients of generating function?

Comment: @ReeteshSingh: You can either expand the generating function using geometric and binomial series expansion and then extract the corresponding coefficient $[a^2b^2c^3]$, which is somewhat cumbersome or you can feed Wolfram Alpha with: SeriesCoefficient[(1+a)(1+b)/(1-c-ab-ac-bc-abc),{a,0,2},{b,0,2},{c,0,3}]

Answer (score 1):

I would define coupled recurrences.  Let $A(x,y,z)$ be the number of strings $x\ a$s, $y\ b$s, and $z\ c$s that ends in $a$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$.  Then $$A(x,y,z)=B(x-1,y,z)+C(x-1,y,z)$$ and similar for $B$.  The recurrence for $C$ is slightly different.  A recursive computer program will make it easy.  There might be a generating function approach.